# Cleaning the buffer-undo-list of unwanted entries

Tags: undo, multiple-cursors, undo-tree-mode

When `multiple-cursors` is deactivated, I would like to remove from the `buffer-undo-list` all entries that look like this:

```
(apply activate-cursor-for-undo 40)

(apply deactivate-cursor-after-undo 38)
```

How can I remove all such entries in one fell swoop?

BACKGROUND:  I am storing the `buffer-undo-list` and `buffer-undo-tree` in the `desktop` restore file, and I'd like to make it smaller so that Emacs will handle starting and shutting down more efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code fragment should do what you want:

```el
(require 'cl-lib)
(setq buffer-undo-list
      (cl-remove-if (lambda (x) (and (consp x) (eq (car x) 'apply)
                     (setq x (cdr x))
                     (consp x) (memq (car x) '(activate-cursor-for-undo deactivate-cursor-after-undo))
                     (setq x (cdr x))
                     (consp x) (numberp (car x))))
            buffer-undo-list))
```

(Note, that this is not fully tested. Comments welcome.)

Comment: I changed `deactivate-cursor-for-undo` to `deactivate-cursor-after-undo` and the new list appears to be clean.  I'll try using the cleaned list for a couple of hours today and see how it works.

Comment: @lawlist Thank you for testing and commenting. I corrected my answer according to your comment.